# PHP - How do i put the X-CSRF-TOKEN in the headers?

Tags: php, curl

How do I put the **$token** or **x-csrf-token** to headers?

The curl post works when I put **x-csrf-token** in the headers manually.

What should I do to put the **$token** or **x-csrf-token** automaticly to headers?

When I make a new curl post that gets token and when I put the token automatic on the headers the response of the curl is **404 bad request**

**This is my script:**

```
$Thing = $_GET['Thing'];
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];

$login = array(
    "cvalue" => $username,
    "ctype" => "Username",
    "password" => $password,
    "captchaToken" => $Thing,
    "captchaProvider" => "PROVIDER_ARKOSE_LABS"
);

$curl = curl_init('https://auth.roblox.com/v2/login'); // There are many links you can login from
curl_setopt_array($curl,array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($login),
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN: '
    ),
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'


));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$size = curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);

curl_close($curl);


#$response1 = explode(" ", $response);

#$cookie = $response1[10];
#$search = ".ROBLOSECURITY=";
#$cookie1 = str_replace($search, '', $cookie);

$headers = substr($response,0,$size);
$array = explode("\n",$headers);
foreach($array as $data){
    if(strpos($data,'csrf')){
        $info = explode(' ',$data);
        break;
    }
}

$csrf = $info[1];
$token = $csrf;
print_r($token);

print_r($response);
```

Comment: Which CSRF-Token are you referring to? Looks like you process the curl response headers to find a csrf-token  ~ is that the token you mean? Where and how are you deriving the `captchaToken`?

Comment: ```function roro_curl_exec($ch,array $additional_headers=[]){$additional_headers[]='X-CSRF-TOKEN: ';curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$additional_headers);return curl_exec($ch);}```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to automatically attach custom headers to all CURL requests. The best way is to wrap your CURL code inside a function and pass the desired CSRF token as a parameter. Here's a demo:

```
function curl_call(array $params, string $csrf_token)
{
    ... curl code here...

    'X-CSRF-TOKEN: '. $csrf_token,

    ... remaining curl code here...
}
```

Then when you want to make a CURL request, you may call the function like this:

```
curl_call(['url' => '...', etc], 'csrf token string here');
```